# JavaScript | Creating dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a shop website with buttons called "add to cart" and have a few `<div>` elements. Every `<div>` element has a class and I want to dynamically add buttons to them by using their class name.

I created code that counts the number of the class, which I need to add to the button and combine it with `for` loop so it will add a button to every `<div>` element **but for some reason, the loop is not working and it only adds to one div**.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.innerHTML = 'Press me';
    button.className = 'btn-styled';
    
    button.onclick = function() {
      // ...
    };
    var classLength = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4").length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < classLength; i++) {
      var container = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4");
      container[i].appendChild(button);
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: you need to create OR clone the button INSIDE the loop

Answer (score 1):

Thank everyone for the help it really was helpful
i fixed it with the following code as you suggested and it seems to work

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var classLength = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4").length;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < classLength; i++){
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.type = 'button';
  button.innerHTML = 'Press me';
  button.className = 'btn-styled';

  button.onclick = function() {
    // ...
  };

  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4");
  container[i].appendChild(button);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I would say my answer is more elegant... But hey, It is your site

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone or create the button inside the loop

Note I added the click event listener to the container

```js
const clicked = (e) => console.log("clicked", e.target.parentNode.firstChild.textContent)
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.type = 'button';
  button.innerHTML = 'Press me';
  button.className = 'btn-styled';

  [...document.querySelectorAll(".col-lg-4.col-md-6.mb-4")] // note the selector
  .forEach(div => div.appendChild(button.cloneNode(true)))

  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", clicked);
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">1. </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">2. </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">3. </div>
</div>
```